# how to replace li elements inside ul in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, foreach

```
let output = "";
Manipulatelist.forEach(element =>
    {
      output += `<li 
                  className="suggestion-active" 
                  onClick=${(e)=>seleted(e)}
                 >
                    ${element.name}
                 </li>`
    });
    document.getElementById('focus').innerHTML = output;
```

**Output** : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

onClick is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing React JSX with original DOM style. Original DOM does not know a thing about `onClick` or `className`, these are JSX attributes that React internally translate to the equivalent DOM attributes and event handlers.

Answer (score -1):

```
onClick={()=>selceted.bind(element.name)}
```

onClick={} not Onclick=${}

remove $

and replace seleted with selected

Comment: `${}` is syntax to append variables in [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Removing `$` wont do what you think it would